# How I can start console application from bat / cmd file, so the console output will be inside bat?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, exe, startup

I tried this:

`start patcher.exe
pause`

Then new console window of my app appears.

and this:

`cmd.exe patcher.exe
pause`

Appears cmd without execution of my prog.

and this:

`cmd.exe
patcher
pause`

Then appears cmd, I must type "exit" and then my pro starts, but in new console again.

I need my console to not appear, but write all messages in that started bat.

Comment: what do you mean with "write in that started bat"?

Comment: My app is already console. Currently, if I start the bat, appears two consoles (bat and my prog). I need that only single console will be shown, like I started it from cmd.

Comment: what happens when you just try `patcher.exe`? (without `start`, `cmd` or something else)

Comment: appears two consoles...

Comment: ok, then the application itself opens another console window. Maybe, there are some parameteres with the application to suppress it (try `patcher.exe /?` or take a look into it's documetation). If not, I'm afraid, you're stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that this didn't work

```
cmd.exe patcher.exe
```

is that isn't how you pass a command to cmd.exe.  Try

```
cmd.exe /C patcher.exe
```

or

```
cmd.exe /K patcher.exe
```

However, that's not likely to remove the duplicate console window.  What's probably going on is that `patcher.exe` is marked as Windows subsystem, so it isn't associated with the console that launches it.  Then it launches child processes which are console applications, and since there's no associated console, a new one is created.

You could try using `EDITBIN patcher.exe /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` to make patcher.exe a console-mode program as well.  Then the console will propagate from parent to patcher (child) to grandchild.  However, since the program wasn't written or tested to run this way, you could find some unintended consequences.

Comment: To be honest, this answer worth more to be accepted, because of editbin thing that really solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

from the comments to your question it looks like the application itself opens another console window.

Maybe, there are some parameteres with the application to suppress it (try patcher.exe /? or take a look into it's documetation). If not, I'm afraid, you're stuck.